# Matching records in a single table and then comparing specific columns from each record

Tags: python, sqlite

I am trying to reduce a population of records in a single table to those elements I do not wish to retain.  Doing so means eliminating from the table those I do wish to keep and leveraging what's left in a separate script to deal with the underlying content on disk.

As a POC I've defined the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE versions (
    keepversion     BOOLEAN,
    albumartist     TEXT,
    album           TEXT,
    track_count     INTEGER,
    dynamicrange    INTEGER,
    __bitspersample INTEGER,
    __frequency_num INTEGER,
    __channels      INTEGER,
    __dirpath       BLOB
);
```

The table contains a record for all instances of `albumartist + album` and related attributes where more than one instance of the same `albumartist` and `album` exists.  As an example:

```
Al Stewart  Time Passages   9   14  16  44.1    2
Al Stewart  Time Passages   9   14  24  96      2
Al Stewart  Year of the Cat 9   14  16  44.1    2
Al Stewart  Year of the Cat 9   14  16  44.1    2
```

I need to iterate through the table, and for each `distinct albumartist, album` compare the attributes of track_count, dynamicrange, __bitspersample, __frequency_num & channels against one another in order to delineate the ones that should be retained. For the purposes of the exercise my intent is to write a 1 to keepversion when that particular version should be retained.

To get every unique albumartist, album combo I've coded a CTE which I'd need to iterate:

```
WITH distinctversions (
    albumartist,
    album
)
AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT albumartist COLLATE nocase AS a,
                    album COLLATE nocase AS b
      FROM versions
)
SELECT albumartist,
       album
  FROM distinctversions;
```

I then need to iterate that against the versions table, looking at each matching occurrence of albumartist, album in versions and run subqueries based on retention criteria.

Stratification rules:

1. only compare albums where channels are =
2. always keep highest resolution,
   regardless of other attributes (highest resolution is defined as greatest `__bitspersample` and `__frequency_num` combination
3. always keep highest `dynamicrange`, regardless of other attributes

thereafter:

4. also keep greatest `track_count`, regardless of other attributes
5. eliminate records with lower `track_count` where all other attributes are equal
6. where all attributes are =, keep one record, eliminate remaining records where all attributes are =

Is there an elegant way to do this using SQLite only or would it be simpler to use Python to do the iteration and interact with SQLite?

Comment: I think for the answer it is relevant to know how complicated the rule is which decides which version is best or better than another. It could be helpful to calculate a quality score for each entry if possible.

Comment: @MichaelButscher, thanks, I added the outline stratification criteria to illustrate.

Comment: I would recommend Python for this. To realize this rule set in Sqlite may be possible but complicated. Moreover some details must be refined, e. g. what to do if multiple entries have highest resolution or dynamic range.